# php foreach question

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code

```
$oldID=-1;
$column=0;
foreach($pv->rawData as $data) {
    if ($oldID!= $data->relativeTypeID) {
        $oldID= $data->relativeTypeID;
        $column++;
        $row=1;
    }

    echo "Row: ".$row.": Column: ".$column.": ID".$data->relativeTypeID."<br>"; 

    // if exists a description
    if($data->description) {
        //insert here in the array
        $pv->results[$data->relativeTypeID][$row][0]= $data->relation;
        $pv->results[$data->relativeTypeID][$row][1]= '';
        $pv->results[$data->relativeTypeID][$row][2] ='';
        $pv->results[$data->relativeTypeID][$row][3]  = '';
        $row++;
    }
}
```

That generates this output:

> Row: 1: Column: 1: ID1
>   Row: 2: Column: 1: ID1
>   Row: 1: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 2: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 3: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 4: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 5: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 6: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 7: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 8: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 9: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 10: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 11: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 1: Column: 3: ID3
>   Row: 1: Column: 4: ID4
>   Row: 1: Column: 5: ID8
>   Row: 2: Column: 5: ID8
>   Row: 3: Column: 5: ID8
>   Row: 1: Column: 6: ID10
>   Row: 2: Column: 6: ID10
>   Row: 3: Column: 6: ID10
>   Row: 4: Column: 6: ID10
>   ...
>   ...

What I want it to do is to stop at the top 4 columns so I want an output like this

> Row: 1: Column: 1: ID1
>   Row: 2: Column: 1: ID1
>   Row: 1: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 2: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 3: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 4: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 5: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 6: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 7: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 8: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 9: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 10: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 11: Column: 2: ID2
>   Row: 1: Column: 3: ID3
>   Row: 1: Column: 4: ID4

As you can see it stopped at column 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this.

```
foreach($pv->rawData as $data){
  if ($oldID!= $data->relativeTypeID){
    $oldID= $data->relativeTypeID;
    $column++;
    $row=1;
  }
  if ($column >=4) break; // Exit the foreach loop if column is equal to or bigger than 4
  echo "Row: ".$row.": Column: ".$column.": ID".$data->relativeTypeID."
```

I'm just being paranoid with my condition, which might as well be $column == 4. Your call. The key is to break out of the loop using the break statement. Check the [documentation for break here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) if you wish.